# EvenBetterAuthorizationSampleは、いったい何をするものをインストールするのでしょうか？

Tags: swift, xcode, objective-c

本当にやりたいことは「MacOSアプリで何度もパスワードを入力させたくない」なのですが、その解決策のために下記のページを発見しました。
[Bypass admin password when changing network configuration](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/52729)

そこに
[EvenBetterAuthorizationSample](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/EvenBetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html) へのリンクがありました。

`Read Me About EvenBetterAuthorizationSample.txt` の `Building the Sample`の項目にある通りplistを修正し実行しました（とは言うもののDevelop IDの確認方法がよくわからなかったため、https://developer.apple.com/ から `Membership Details`の項目の`Team ID`の値で置き換えました）。

スキームは下記のように設定して実行しましました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

実行結果は、下記です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Install以外のどのボタンを押しても

```
error NSCocoaErrorDomain / 4099
connection invalidated
```

というエラーになります。

ダメ元でInstallを押すと、パスワードを要求されるので入力すると

`error CFErrorDomainLaunchd / 4`

と表示されました。

結局、このサンプルコードは何をインストールしようとしているのでしょうか？
このサンプルコードと
[Bypass admin password when changing network configuration](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/52729)
の質問タイトルであります、パスワードをバイパスするという関係性がいまいちピンと来ません。
このサンプルコードは何をしようとしているのでしょうか？

なんとなく
[AuthorizationCreate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1397453-authorizationcreate?language=objc)
に記載されている

> You can also use this function to preauthorize rights by specifying the kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize mask. Preauthorization is most useful when a right has a zero timeout. For example, you can preauthorize in the application and if it succeeds, call the helper tool and request authorization. This eliminates calling the helper tool if the user cannot later authorize the specified rights.

の中に記載されている `the helper tool` と何か関係している気もしています（とはいえヘルパーツールとは？という感じで言葉以上の理解がいまいち進んでないですが）

同ページの

> In macOS 10.4 and later, you can also pass a user name and password in order to authorize a user without user interaction. Possible values for this parameter are listed in Security.framework/Headers/AuthorizationTags.h.
> The data passed in this parameter is not stored in the authorization reference; it is used only during authorization. If you are not passing any data in this parameter, pass the constant kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment.

ところも気になっており、これで本当にやりたかったパスワードを何度も入力させたくないを達成できないか別途調査中です。

（本当はSwiftでコードを作成しているのですが、この手の権限の情報がObjective-Cでの情報ばかりがネットにあるので、仕方なくObjective-Cで情報を集めています）

Comment: 自身で調べた結果「EvenBetterAuthorizationSample を使いたい」であればいいのですが、そうでなければ [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701) に陥っていませんか？

Comment: おっしゃるとおりなんですが、関連しそうなことくらいしかわかっておらず、その上、実行時にエラーになってしまうため、EvenBetterAuthorizationSampleを深堀り（調査を続行）すべきか、そうでないかわからないんですよね。そもそも何がどうなるべきかもわからないので、この実行時エラーをどう解消すべきかも、深堀りしていかないとわからない。そこで、そもそも何をすべきものなのか質問してみようと思いました。何をするものなのかわかれば、これが私が調べるべきものかそうでないものかわかると考えたため。（とはいえ、本当にやりたいことを質問すべきというのもわかります）